# Substring from str in py

Tags: python, regex, xml, string, substring

so I got this now, I have to extract a date from a str, (This comes from a XML file, but the tag I need is inside another tag, which don't allow extracting the date directly, so I have to extract all the Main tags, and then extract the info, from that converting to a str) but when I convert the Object of the XML to a Str, and try to extract the date with RE, I got an error, here's my code:

```
valor_uno = datos.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Description")[0]
vlr = str(valor_uno)
valor = re.search('<cbc:DueDate>(.+?)</cbc:DueDate>', vlr).group(1)
print(valor)
```

With that code, I got the next error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

And this is a small piece of the tags inside the XML, where is the cbc:DueDate tag:

> <cbc:IssueDate>2022-06-16</cbc:IssueDate>
> <cbc:IssueTime>17:44:00-05:00</cbc:IssueTime>
> <cbc:DueDate>2022-07-16</cbc:DueDate>
> <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>01</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>

How can i extract the date (2022-07-16)?

EDIT = This is kind of the XML format I got:

> <cac:Attachment>

> <cbc:Description>

......

> <cbc:IssueDate>2022-06-16</cbc:IssueDate>
> <cbc:IssueTime>17:44:00-05:00</cbc:IssueTime>
> <cbc:DueDate>2022-07-16</cbc:DueDate>
> <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>01</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
> ......

> <</cbc:Description>>

> <</cac:Attachment>>

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `re.search` here; the data you want is contained in an XML element so you should be able to extract it using your XML parser.

Comment: You are showing only fragments of code and XML. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The problem with the XML file, is the format they have, it used to have all the info in the tags, with a main tag, but in this case, the date is in a tag inside another tag, wich is inside in a main tag, example: Main tag = <cac:Attachment>, subTag = <cbc:Description> here in description start all the other tags wich use to be 500 lines in the IDE, before the </cbc:Description> closes, that´s why I can´t put al the XML file

Comment: It is not clear why it is a problem that a tag is inside another tag. "Tags inside tags" is what XML is about.

Comment: The problem here is, the tag <cbc:description> is the mainTag for all the tags in the attachment, but if I do: valor_uno = datos.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Description")[0]
valor_uno.firstChild.data, I get all the data from the tag, all the subtags, and all the info, not only the first one, or so

Comment: does the xml have a schema?